# Yii 2 Custom Module Namespace for Models

Tags: module, yii2

Is there anyway to change the namespace of the Module and use it as a namespace of my models?

I'm building a project using the basic app template of yii2.

What I want is to have a centralized namespace so that when I use the module into different project and reuse the models inside it, (either basic or advanced template), I won't have to change the namespace based on its root directory.

Answer (score 1):

This will possible with Yii2 aliases.

first put all your models in your custom folder and set it alias name Yii config file. like below

```
// an alias of a file path
Yii::setAlias('@myFolder', '/path/to/foo');
```

finally, update your all models namespace based on this alias one time. like below.

```
namespace myFolder\models\xxx;
```

now you can copy this folder to any yii2 app and just set alias name, like above i mention.

Note:- directory will be independent like below and namespace will based on this directory.

```
folderName
   ->models
       ->xxxxx
       ->xxxxx
        .....
// and namespace should add all the models like below
namespace folderName\models;

// while using these models, you can import like below
import myFolder\xxxxxx;
```

Comment: Thanks @Irfan, but I can't make it worked. I added this line in the `init()` method of my Module class: 
`$this->setAliases(['@main' => Yii::getAlias('@app') . '/modules/main']);`

and tried to set the namespace of my models to `namespace main\models` but got a `Namespace missing?` error

Comment: you should set this alias in config not in module. try this.

Comment: Have you set this alias in config/web.php?

Comment: No. Do I need to set it there too?

Comment: You just need to set it in config that's it. no need to set it anywhere and i updated my answer. please have a look. you will get more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the composer.json file find

```
{
   .....
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/" #<-key=namespace value=dirname
        }
  }
  ......
}
```

run composer update